# How to prevent expansion-panel overflowing on a toolbar?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to put a mat-expansion-panel inside a mat-toolbar, but the panel keeps overflowing on top.

I saw that when i put a `display: block` on the toolbar, the panel won't overflow, but when i put a `display: flex`, it will. I also don't know how to search for this kind of issue.

Reproduction:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/expansion-toolbar

Anyone knows if i can keep the flex display and preventing the panel from overflowing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your css file:

```
.first-tool-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
```

and add the `.first-tool-bar` class to the toolbar like so:

```
<mat-toolbar class="first-tool-bar">
```